# Convert input to a string in Python

Tags: python

I want to wrap the colour input in quotes within python:

```
def main():
    colour = input("please enter a colour")
```

So if I enter red into the input box it automatically makes it "red"

I'm not sure how to do this, would it be something along the lines of:

```
def main():
    colour = """ + input("please enter a colour") + """
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that this doesn't pass syntactically, as Python thinks the second `"` is the end of the string (the syntax highlighting in your post shows how it's being interpreted). The nicest to read solution is to use single quotes for the string: `'"'`.

Alternatively, you can escape characters (if you wish to, for example, use both types of quote in a string) with a backslash: `"\""`

A nice way of doing this kind of insertion of a value, rather than many concatenations of strings, is to use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
colour = '"{}"'.format(input("please enter a colour"))
```

This can do a lot of things, but here, we are simply using it to insert the value we pass in where we put `{}`. (Note that pre-2.7, you will need to give the number of the argument to insert e.g: `{0}` in this case. Past that version, if you don't give one, Python will just use the next value).

Do note that in Python 2.x, you will want `raw_input()` rather than `input()` as in 2.x, the latter evaluates the input as Python, which could lead to bad things. In 3.x, the behaviour was fixed so that `input()` behaves as `raw_input()` did in 2.x.

Comment: @A.R.S. Cheers, I've added in the bit from your post about ``raw_input()`` in case the asker is using 2.x.